# Highcharts > Tooltip > Crosshair: How to set horizontal crosshair to snap to CLOSE in OHLC series?

Tags: highcharts

Currently it is default to snap at HIGH and there is no option to set it to snap to CLOSE.

I want to edit `highstock.js` but I don't know where. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find in Highstock.src.js `Tooltip.refresh` function. There is:

```
val = i ? pick(point.stackY, point.y) : point.x;
```

Try co change to `point.low` instead of `point.y`. In general modify code under `if (crosshairsOptions) { .. }` condition.